# Westell vs. Linksys - which one should I keep around?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, comparison

So Verizon is offering a free netbook to new DSL subscribers, and I don't have any particular affinity for Comcast, so I decided to try it out.

With Comcast (which is actually still running), I have the following setup:
- Motorola cable modem
- Linksys WRT54g v 2.2 running Tomato and boosted output power

I have this unit set to forward BitTorrent, SSH, and icecast ports to one machine at home.

Verizon unexpectedly sent me a modem for my new service that also functions as a wireless access point and a router. It's a Westell 7500. It seems to be almost as configurable as my Linksys, and it looks like there is no need to boost the output power in order to get up to my office. The only missing feature appears to be DynDNS.com updating; the new router uses TSIG authentication which is only available on paid accounts, and I can just punt this to one of my computers.

So, is there anything I am missing that would be worth me keeping the Linksys around? Does this router have any hidden gotchas?

Comment: Not saying it's the same question, but you might want to give this a quick read: http://superuser.com/questions/39199/what-are-the-disadvantages-if-any-of-accessing-the-internet-through-two-or-more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a Westell 7500 for one day, and so far, I don't like it.

One workaround that I have discovered for DynDNS:

If you use Mac OS X, there is a DynDNS widget that will update DynDNS for you.

http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/networking_security/dyndnsupdater.html

Comment: That's basically what I did, except I used a command-line one from MacPorts. I also just turned off the wireless on the Westell. It was flaky.

Answer (score 1):

You're 2/3 toward having separate secure and insecure networks behind the same connection. Buy another inexpensive wireless router and connect this new router and the linksys to the Westell. You can then configure your linksys to use WPA2 for an encrypted network and configure the other to be open.

One use case for this is connecting devices that don't support strong security (e.g. older TiVos, Nintendo DS) or visitors to your network connection while providing a safe wireless network for your computers and other newer devices.

Comment: If the Verizon modem/router thingy also has wireless, then isn't he all the way there?