# Home network with two routers and just one Wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, adsl, subnet

I know it is a pretty lame question, but I am not a pro in networking, so I will still ask it. And I will try to explain details where possible.

I want to create the following setup:

Phone line is in the hallway downstairs. I connect unit A to the phone line. Unit A is a combined ADSL modem + WiFi router + 4-port ethernet switch. (correct me if I am not using the terms correctly). The model is [D-Link 3680](https://www.talktalk-labs.com/trials/dlink-3680-router-trial/).

*Note: I know the modem functions correctly and connects to the Internet (I have tested it). I also know that DHCP in the router functions correctly and I can connect to the internet with my laptop.*

I disable WiFi in unit A and run cable (in fact a [PowerLine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-line_communication) link) upstairs to the third floor.

*Note: I have checked that I can connect to the internet on the the other side of the link. I still get address from DHCP of my router and everything is fine*

What I want to do now, is instead of connecting to the cable on the third floor, hook up another router that I have. Unit B: [Huawei HG533](http://www.theproductsite.com/blog/talktalk-huawei-hg533-router-review/): a combined ADSL modem + WiFi router + 4-port ethernet switch with USB port for Storage Devices. I want to have wifi enabled on it and I want to connect to the internet through it. Obviously I disable modem functionality in this device and just connect the ethernet cable to the uplink.

The problem is, that I cannot connect to the internet once connected to the Unit B. And I cannot ping unit A.

So, could anyone sketch a correct network topology for this setup? What settings do I have to look at? Where do I even start. Which one of two units (or both) need(s) to run DHCP server? Do they have to be on the same subnet? How do I setup default gateways.

```
   [Internet]
       |
  [Phone Line]
       |
       |
|--------------|                 |---------------|                                        
|   Unit A     |                 |   Unit B      |          |---------------|
|  ADSL modem  |---[powerline]---| ADSL disabled |--[WiFi]--|   Laptop(s)   |
|              |                 |       DHCP?   |          |---------------|
|--------------|                 |---------------|
                                         |
                                         |
                                       [USB]
                                         |
                                 |---------------|
                                 |      HDD      |
                                 |---------------|
```

Oh, and if anyone is interested in *why am i doing it*. It is simple: Reason 1: I don't want to have my WiFi Router downstairs because signal is weak on the third floor. Reason 2: I use USB port and connect my 1Tb hdd to it and I don't want to leave it in the hallway, because I live in the flatshare with people I don't really know. Reason 3: I want to have WiFi within my room, not just an ethernet cable.

Sorry for being such a n00b, any advice will be appreciated.
Oh, and I have read [this thread](https://superuser.com/q/50899/281154), but does not provide enough explanation.

UPDATE: in response to CharlieRB's comment, here is a picture of the Unit B:

[image]

Comment: When you say "connect the ethernet cable to the uplink", is there a port actually called uplink? Or are you referring to the ADSL port? Or is it the WAN port?

Comment: There is one marked as "fiber". I believe it to be the uplink. It is a standard RJ45 though. I will upload the picture to my original post.

Comment: I'm unsure if this is off topic here and should be sent to Server fault.

Comment: @MaxRied I considered posting it on ServerFault, but I believe it is more relevant on SU, because it has nothing to deal with Servers and it is just a simple basic setup of a home network. In fact ServerFault rules clearly state that the site is NOT for [**Anything in a home or development environment**](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). Yet, if admins will decide to migrate it to ServerFault I will not mind as long as I receive some answers.

Comment: I had a look at your Huawei. Its manual is really economical... You want to try: 1) Disable the DHCP server on the Huawei. 2) Set it to bridge mode and make itself get its IP using DHCP from the D-Link Router or set manually to one in the D-Link's subnet. 3) DO NOT use the Fibre port. Connect the PowerLine adapter to one of the yellow sockets.

Comment: @MaxRied, I will try it today and update the post with results

Comment: I agree with @MaxRied. I have a similar setup in my house (but I run two wifi networks, one upstairs and one downstairs). In my setup, I have a combined ADSL modem and router connected to the phoneline downstairs running a DHCP server. I have connected an Ethernet cable from a LAN socket on this router to a LAN socket (not WAN) on a router upstairs with the DHCP server disabled which broadcasts a separate wireless network. The upstairs router behaves as a switch and IP addresses are distributed to devices connecting to the upstairs wifi by the DHCP server on the downstairs router.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use an AP?

Comment: @MaxRied, could you explain, what do you mean by using AP?

Comment: @smc There are devices dedicated to this function, coupling a wired with a wireless network.

Comment: @MaxRied I am planning to switch to another device soon. However for now I want to stick to the HW that is available. Thanks for your help man. I have posted the description of the final solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I am finally answering my own question here. The answer is derived from the comments by  Max Ried and James Womack. I wouldn't have figured it out on my own. In fact, my original setup was 100% correct. The problem was that Unit B (Huawei HG533) has a bug that does not allow clients connected to it to use external DHCP server. The only change I made was setting static IPs and now everything works.

So what I did was:

- I set address of Unit A (D-Link modem + router) to 192.168.1.2 and connected it to the phoneline.
- I have connected powerline adapter to one of the LAN ports of Unit A and plugged it into the mains
- On the top floor of the apartment I have plugged another powerline adapter into the mains and connected it to one of the LAN ports of Unit B. I have figured out that it does not make any difference if I connect it to one of LAN ports or to the one labeled as "Fiber" - result is the same
- I have disabled WiFi in unit A and enabled WiFi in unit B
- I now connect to unit B and I have access to NAS, connected to unit B and to the internet available through Unit A.

**However**: I did not manage to setup DHCP. This seems to be the problem that initially did not allow me to create desired setup. I am currently using static IP address for both Unit A, Unit B and all clients connected to Unit B.

There is a setting called "DHCP transparent transparrent transmission" and another one called "DHCP relay" - both have no effect. I have tried enabling DHCP for Unit A and dissabling it for Unit B and putting it into Bridge mode with Transparent DHCP transmission no effect.

Quick search on the internet showed that this is a *feature* of Huawei HG533 and it seems like no one can get it to transmit DHCP transparently from LAN.

[[Link 1]](http://community.talktalk.co.uk/t5/Unlimited-Broadband/HG533-DHCP-over-WiFi-Issues/td-p/786499)

[[Link 2]](http://community.talktalk.co.uk/t5/Unlimited-Broadband/HG533-and-DHCP-Server/td-p/853645)

Anyway, I am happy with my current setup even though it is static IP. I am planning to replace unit B (Huawei HG533) with Asus RT-N16 running openWrt soon anyway.

Thanks to everyone who helped me to sort this out.

**UPDATE:** here are screenshots from the interface of Unit B (Huawei)
[image]

[image]

Comment: That's protection from rogue DHCP-Servers.

Comment: @MaxRied Could you elaborate on rogue DHCP-Server protection, plz? What does it have to do with having a couple of tick boxes that don't work? I am interested

Comment: Didn't tell you it's functioning correctly. Just saying not forwarding DHCP through a gateway is often desired behavior.

Comment: Oh, ok. I get it now

Comment: Having multiple DHCPs in one routing domain WILL bring you in severe trouble. You won't configure your network with more than one DHCP-server, except you REALLY know what you are doing. Or by accident. And that's what this setting is protecting you from.

Comment: Well, it also protects me from having even one working DHCP )) Yet, your comment about REALLY knowing what I am doing is very relevant. I am quiet a n00b in networking

Comment: Sorry if you already wrote it, but it just comes to my mind: Why don't you reverse your setup and use your Huawei as the DHCP server?

Comment: Because then my client machine will receive correct address on the network and will be able to see both Huawei and D-Link, but it will receive the instruction from DHCP to use Huawei as the default gateway  and thus will be cut off the internet. I need to have D-Link as the default gateway. I cannot instruct Huawei to sent default gateway address different then its own address

Comment: OK, Yoda says: limited Huawei thing it is.